# compare one value with each value of array which is inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
var array1 = ['me','you','our'];
var array2 = ['us','they','all'];
```

I have another array

```
var arrayList = [array1, array2]
```

Now I have one value which I want to compare with each value of each array inside arrayList.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
var yourValue;
for(var i=0;i<arrayList.length;i++)
{
   for(var j=0;j<arrayList[i].length;j++)
   {
      if(arrayList[i][j] == yourValue)
      {
         //
         //
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is right but I want to exit both for loop  if value is equal

Answer (score 0):

```
var val='your value';
for(var i=0;i<arrayList.length;i++)
{
if(arrayList[i].indexOf(val)>-1){
// do something
// and break
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `arrayList` then use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var val = 'you';
for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
    if(arrayList[i].indexOf(val) !== -1){
        alert('match');
    }
}
```